# Block iFrame embeds via S3 bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to prevent people from embedding my website in an iframe except for a specific URL, my primary domain.

I am hosting the entire front-end on an S3 bucket. Is this something that can be accomplished with the S3 Bucket Policy?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to limit this by using the "aws:Referer" condition.

Taken from this page:
https://asecure.cloud/a/s3_http_referrer/

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://www.example.com/*",
                        "http://example.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for you response, no luck on that policy update.

Answer (score 0):

Its not really possible with proper authentication and authorization. [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html) clearly says you shouldn't relay on `aws:Referer`:

> Unauthorized parties can use modified or custom browsers to provide any aws:Referer value that they choose. Therefore, **do not use aws:Referer to prevent unauthorized parties from making direct AWS requests**.